# how to shift columns in pandas DataFrame dynamically and independently?

Tags: python, pandas

What I wish to achieve is to be able to normalise my values so that they all start on a arbitrary day-zero. Imagine the DataFrame below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [4, 5, 0], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 0], [7, 8, 9]]), 
              columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], 
              index = ['1/1/2000', '1/1/2001', '1/1/2002', '1/1/2003', '1/1/2004', '1/1/2005'])
```

Which results in the following:

```
            a   b   c
1/1/2000    1   0   0
1/1/2001    4   5   0
1/1/2002    7   8   9
1/1/2003    7   8   9
1/1/2004    4   5   0
1/1/2005    7   8   9
```

What I am trying to achieve is the find the first non-zero value in each column, and shift the values in that column to the index zero. so the final dataFrame looks similar to this:

```
            a   b   c
1/1/2000    1   5   9
1/1/2001    4   8   9
1/1/2002    7   8   0
1/1/2003    7   5   9
1/1/2004    4   8   0
1/1/2005    7   0   0
```

I tried to use a shift, and I can use something like this:

```
df.b = df.b.shift(periods = -1, fill_value = 0)
```

but currently I do not know any pandas-friendly way to do this without using for loops, etc.

Appreciate if some can help on the best to find the first non-zero value and then shifting the values correctly to index zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get number of shifts by compare for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html), then add cumulative sum by [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), compare `0` and last count `True`s by `sum`. Then use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda function and for shifts select values of `Series`:

```
s = df.ne(0).cumsum().eq(0).sum()
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(periods = -s[x.name], fill_value = 0))
print (df)
          a  b  c
1/1/2000  1  5  9
1/1/2001  4  8  9
1/1/2002  7  8  0
1/1/2003  7  5  9
1/1/2004  4  8  0
1/1/2005  7  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clever answer, can you please explain why the second line work? I am new to pandas and using my current project as a learning opportunity.

I am particularly confused with -s[x.name], I understand s is a DataSeries, but I cannon understand what x refers to and how x.name makes sense for s, thanks again.