# Pandas/xarray - Shift horizontally values dynamically based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

I want to shift horizontally each row of my dataframe `test_1` following the values in the corresponding rows from another dataframe `df_x`. The value in each row of `df_x` should define the amount of steps shifted to the left.

`test_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [10,12,13,14], [20, 22, 23,24]])`

`df_x = pd.DataFrame([[1],[3],[2]])`

My expected output would be:

```
Out[157]: 
    0   1   2   3
0   2   3   4  NA
1  14  NA  NA  NA
2  23  24  NA  NA
```

I tried adapting from an answer to a similar question ([how to shift columns in pandas DataFrame dynamically and independently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558581/how-to-shift-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-dynamically-and-independently)), and used this:
`test_1.apply(lambda x: x.shift(periods = -df_x.loc[x,:]), axis = 1)`.

However, I keep getting the following error:

`KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64'). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"`

PS: If anyone also knows how to do this without converting from Xarray to Pandas, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> test_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [10,12,13,14], [20, 22, 23,24]])
>>> test_1
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4
1   10  12  13  14
2   20  22  23  24
```

We can start by transposing the `DataFrame` like so :

```py
>>> test_1 = test_1.T
>>> test_1
    0   1   2
0   1   10  20
1   2   12  22
2   3   13  23
3   4   14  24
```

Then, using `df_x` we can use a `for` loop to select the correct columns to `shift` and re-transpose `test_1` again to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df_x = pd.DataFrame([[0],[1],[2]])
>>> line=0
>>> for val in list(df_x.values.flatten()): 
...     test_1[line] = test_1[line].shift(periods=-val)
...     line+=1
>>> test_1 = test_1.T
    0       1       2       3
0   1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0
1   12.0    13.0    14.0    NaN
2   23.0    24.0    NaN     NaN
```

For `df_x = pd.DataFrame([[0],[2],[2]])` :

```py
>>> test_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [10,12,13,14], [20, 22, 23,24]]) 
>>> test_1 = test_1.T 
>>> df_x = pd.DataFrame([[0],[2],[2]]) 

>>> line=0
>>> for val in list(df_x.values.flatten()): 
...     test_1[line] = test_1[line].shift(periods=-val)
...     line+=1  
>>> test_1 = test_1.T         
>>> test_1
    0       1       2   3
0   1.0     2.0     3.0 4.0
1   13.0    14.0    NaN NaN
2   23.0    24.0    NaN NaN
```

For `df_x = pd.DataFrame([[2],[2],[0]])` :

```py
>>> test_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [10,12,13,14], [20, 22, 23,24]]) 
>>> test_1 = test_1.T 
>>> df_x = pd.DataFrame([[2],[2],[0]]) 

>>> line=0
>>> for val in list(df_x.values.flatten()): 
...     test_1[line] = test_1[line].shift(periods=-val)
...     line+=1  
>>> test_1 = test_1.T         
>>> test_1
    0       1       2       3
0   3.0     4.0     NaN     NaN
1   13.0    14.0    NaN     NaN
2   20.0    22.0    23.0    24.0
```

And for `df_x = pd.DataFrame([[1],[3],[2]])` :

```py
>>> test_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [10,12,13,14], [20, 22, 23,24]]) 
>>> test_1 = test_1.T 
>>> df_x = pd.DataFrame([[1],[3],[2]]) 

>>> line=0
>>> for val in list(df_x.values.flatten()): 
...     test_1[line] = test_1[line].shift(periods=-val)
...     line+=1  
>>> test_1 = test_1.T         
>>> test_1
    0       1       2     3
0   2.0     3.0     4.0   NaN
1   14.0    NaN     NaN   NaN
2   23.0    24.0    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It worked well, but if I change my `df_x` from `[0],[1],[2]` to `[0],[2],[2]`, the results stop working: 

test_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [10,12,13,14], [20, 22, 23,24]])
test_1 = test_1.T
df_x = pd.DataFrame([[0],[2],[2]])
for val in df_x.values:
    test_1[val[0]] = test_1[val[0]].shift(periods=-val[0])
test_1 = test_1.T

test_1
Out[285]: 
      0     1     2     3
0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1  10.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

Comment: I updated the answer to cover your second example. Does it solve your question ?

Comment: As you added a new example in your question, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I see that @tlentali answered your question as an alternative answer you can also use this:

```
df_x_seq = np.squeeze((df_x.values))
Lens=np.squeeze((test_1.shape[1]-df_x).values)
    Id=-1
def shift(row):
    global Id
    Id+=1
    array=np.empty((row.shape[0]))
    array[:]=np.nan
    if Lens[Id]!=row.shape[0]:
        array[:Lens[Id]]=row.values[df_x_seq[Id]:]
        return  array 
    else:
        return row
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The answer seems to work, but when I changed `df_x = pd.DataFrame([[2],[2],[3]])`, I got an error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (1,)`

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I've got this issue with the `df_x_seq` not being defined.

Comment: Oh it's just squeezed version of df_x.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. I accepted the other answer because it came first, but this one is perfect as well. thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There was a third answer that was also very good, but got deleted for some reason.

Solution:

```
test_2=(df_x.rename(columns={0:'s'})
            .join(test_1)
            .apply(lambda x:x.shift(-(x['s'])),axis=1)
            .drop(columns=['s']))
```